# Html - Changing Width and Height of a slider

Tags: php, html, css, slider

I'm creating a dynamic website with PHP and HTML for educational purposes .

I've been trying to create a 'slideshow' like the one in this video. 
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=L-vBR3vzOe8

However I've been having difficulties to set the desired amount of width and height ( it is way too small). I've been playing around with the code for the last hour and I can't figure it out.

Is anyone kind enough to point me in the right direction ?

My code is looking something like this:

CSS code:

```
@keyframes slider {

0% {
    left: 0;
}

20% {
    left: 0;
}

25% {
    left: -100%;
}

45% {
    left: -100%;

}

50% {
    left: -200%;

}

70% {
    left: -200%;
}

75% {
    left: -300%;
}

95% {
    left: -300%;
}

100% {
    left: -400%;

}

}

#slider {
    overflow: hidden;

}

#slider figure img {
    width:20%;
    float: left;

}

#slider figure {
    position: relative;
    width: 500%;
    margin: 0;
    left: 0;
    text-align: left;
    font-size: 0;
    animation: 20s slider infinite; 

}
```

This is my HTML code:

```
  <div id ="slider" >
             <figure>
             <img src ="Images/img1.jpg">
             <img src ="Images/img2.jpg">
             <img src ="Images/img3.jpg">
             <img src ="Images/img4.jpg">

            </figure>
        </div>
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Working sample: [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/w900p6vy/)

Total width is 100% and height is auto

You can change width of #slider

```css
#slider {
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 50%;
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much . I just changed my desired width and length from #slider and it worked fine.

Answer (score 0):

You need to change width of `#slider` (div with ID `slider`), which is a container for this slideshow.

Most likely:

- place, where slider div is located, can't be larger
- images you are using are not large enough
- some other styling related issues, which can be hard to detect
  without having full access to that page.

If you wan't to create dynamic page with this approach, then you will always need change also keyframes and width of `figure` depending on image count.

Point in right direction - More faster approach would be using ready to use libraries like [bxslider](http://bxslider.com/) - this is very well documented.

Comment: I will try to use bxslider right now. I will make further comments after I try it.

Comment: Please read first, then ask. (Yes, it can, fade, slide, captions, hovers buttons, and even custom awful  CSS styles).